How do i make a live ubuntu USB
I am looking for a simple solution that does not require installing this operating system to my internal drives. I know that there is a feature inside of the installer that allows you to try ubuntu. However, this is not what I wish for as I want the USB stick to behave as a normal built in drive so that I can have persistent storage. that can be used as an alternative to windows 11 as it does not fully support my system due to the silly TPM 2.0 requirement that my PC has not got. As a result it refuses to go past version 22H2. I wish to keep that and only that on my primary drive so that I can still have that as it is untouched. I just want the Ubuntu version of the WindowsToGo scheme that is currently around. Please help me as soon a possible. Thank you for the help if you choose to help me, so thank you. :)

See the original section of this answer. You will need 2 USB drives. One for the installation source. The second for the installation destination.

This question is similar to: Installing Ubuntu in a external hard drive and NOT placing GRUB of my C: hard drive. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Download the iso version of the operating system you want of Ubuntu.
Create the Live USB with the iso of this operating system.
Boot the computer from the USB
Once the loading is complete.
Download the image you will use for the persistent USB
Open a terminal
Run in it:
wget http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/24.04/release/xubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Once the iso is downloaded
Continue running
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install mkusb
sudo -H mkusb xubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso p

From the options that appear in the terminal, choose the second “e” and press Enter.
Choose the USB drive where you will install it.
Check the box to start the installation and press “ok”.
In the 4th and 5th windows we press “q” to select default options.
Last step is to select the percentage of the USB allocated to the persistent operating system.

You can use the following command to download the Ubuntu 24.04 ISO from official Canonical servers using wget: wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/24.04/ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.

Thank you for this help, it has come in really useful
